# .apk file not found in bin after exporting the project?

Tags: android, apk

I am exporting my project using Eclipse indigo which earlier was working fine but now it is exporting the project but the .apk file is not found in bin folder . Any one could provide some help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to clean and build it. Then you have to run in emulator. After that check your apk will be in bin folder.

Comment: You don't even need to run it in the emulator (or on a device). If you have *Eclipse* setup not to launch new devices or *avd's* automatically, then you can just click *run*. This builds the *apk*, but doesn't run the app anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you click left button mouse on project -> android tool -> export signed -> you can choose where to save .apk